# Checking if files have the same date from the name, Python 3

Tags: python

I have some files that have the date saved within them, e.g. `foo161108part.txt`,`baarr161108part2.txt`,`python141106part2.txt`

So far I've listed the directory with:

```
directoryFiles = []
for name in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
    if name.endswith('.txt'):
        files.append(name)
print(files)
```

There are quite a lot of different files with different dates, and I'd like to see how many come up on the same date.

Thanks!

Comment: You can use a regex or just go through your string in a loop and detect the first number. Then, get the six following numbers and compare what is identical.

Comment: Thanks @chris-rands -- how would I split though? Since the first part of the file is a different length for each file (e.g. the foo and baarr)

Comment: Splitting is not applicable here. The loop on the string is really the most obvious and is the easiest way to go. EDIT : it of course implies having only letters before the date. Otherwise it'll be a little bit more difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If *date* part is a crucial part to search within a file name, consider the following approach:

```
import re

counts = {}
pattern = re.compile(r'^.*(\d{6}).*?$')

for f in os.listdir('text_files'):
    m = re.match(pattern, f)
    if m:
        date_value = m.group(1)
        counts[date_value] = counts[date_value]+1 if counts.get(date_value) else 1

print(counts)
```

The output:

```
{'161108': 2, '141106': 1}
```

As for regex:

> using **re.compile()** and saving the resulting regular expression object
>   for reuse is more efficient when the expression will be used several
>   times in a single program

Comment: Would there be a work around if the characters after the date are numbers? E.g. foo161108200.txt?

Comment: it will work, but it considers only the first 6 digits which point to some date, all the next numbers will be ignored. In other words, `161108` will point to the current date `2016 11 08` and next part `200` hasn't much matter in  our case

Comment: Thanks! And how about if the date was day/month/year, would the regex need to be changed?

Comment: of course, if date part contains slashes, they should be considered like `\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}`

Answer (score 0):

If the aim is to just compare the content of the files, the ideal way will be to use [`filecmp`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/filecmp.html#module-filecmp) module. This modules provides [`filecmp.cmp()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/filecmp.html#filecmp.cmp) method which:

> Compare the files named f1 and f2, returning True if they seem equal, False otherwise.

Example:

```
>>> import filecmp
>>> filecmp.cmp('undoc.rst', 'undoc.rst') 
True
>>> filecmp.cmp('undoc.rst', 'index.rst') 
False
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regex and Counter class of python for this purpose:

```
import re
from collections import Counter

files = ['foo161108part.txt','baarr161108part2.txt','python141106part2.txt']

dates = []
for f in files:
    m = re.match(r"^.*(\d{6}).*\.txt$", f)
    if m:
        dates.append(m.group(1))
print dates
print Counter(dates)
```

Output:

```
['161108', '161108', '141106']
Counter({'161108': 2, '141106': 1})
```